# JavaScript - returning [object Object]

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a dynamic form that appends groups of input fields to the page based on user input.  Because of some additional functionality that needs to be attached to some of these elements, I need to create them as JSON objects.  When I test this method with only one input element, the element is appended to the page, no problem.  However, when I try to incorporate a second element into the process, I get `[object Object] [object Object]` appended to the page instead.

Here's the gist...

```
//THIS IS THE PROBLEM FUNCTION, WHICH IS TRIGGERED BY THE CHANGE FUNCTION BELOW
function generateInput(siteNumber, x){

    select = $("<select/>", {
                id: 'select'+siteNumber+''+x+'',
                name: 'select'+siteNumber+'['+x+']'
                }).append(list);

    notes = $("<input/>", {
                type: 'text',
                id: 'notes'+siteNumber+''+x+'',
                name: 'notes'+siteNumber+'['+x+']'
                });


    //IF I RETURN ONE OR THE OTHER, NO PROBLEM
    return select + notes;
};

$(document).on("change", ".number_select", function(){
    siteNumber = $(this).parent().attr('data-site_number');
    numberFound = $(this).val();

    for(x = 1; x <= numberFound; x++){
        this['inputArray' + siteNumber].push(generateInput(siteNumber, x));
     };

     $(this).parent().append(this['inputArray' + siteNumber]);
});
```

I imagine that the problem is with the way that I am returning the elements at the end of `generateInput`, but I'm not sure of the proper way to handle this.  Basically, what I am aiming to get is the select element with the text element sitting next to it.

Thanks very much!

Comment: `notes` is an object. `+ notes` will stringify the object thus `[object Object]`

Comment: JSON is not an object. JSON is a string. Don't call JavaScript objects JSON.

Comment: I spruced it up so it jives with the answers below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `+` operator will call the `toString()` method of one of the terms if the other is a string.

This is not what you want, what you want instead is to merge the jQuery objects into one

Thus

```
return select + notes;
```

Could become ([see jquery doc for `add`](https://api.jquery.com/add/)):

```
return select.add(notes);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have two objects and add them, they are cast to string using `.toString()` method, which returns string `"[object Object]"`. It means this is an object, which is instance of `Object`. If you want to return both object, you can return them for example as array:

```
return [species, notes];
```

Then you can pass the result to the `.push()` method using [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator):

```
this['inputArray' + siteNumber].push(...generateInput(siteNumber, x));
```

However, since the `.push()` method accepts many arguments, you don't even need to modify this part of code.

Comment: I'm accepting the other answer because it works better in a few other circumstances that arise on the form, but this is a good answer.